# Input type number unable to format value with number pipe

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use number pipe to format my value inside `<input type=number />` in my Angular App.

The pipe should format the value with three decimal, by default the value is 1 and in input box it should be displayed as `1.000`, but instead if i use any `digitsInfo` after `number` no value will be displayed inside `input`.

I've tryed to make a reproduction of the problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u3muhv?file=src/app/app.component.html) but in it the behaviour is as it have to be while in my Angular App is looks like the following:

[image]

As you could see on the gif if i add `'1.3'` after `number:` value inside input will disappear..

The problem is not in `plu.qta` value as even if i set a static `1` as value it will still not display any value inside input.

**UPDATE:**
ok i just found the problem, the issue is that i `registeredLocale` to italian and if i remove it from my `app.module` all is formatted correctly.

My app.module looks like this:

```
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
registerLocaleData(localeIt);

@NgModule...
...
providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it'}]
```

So by keeping the locale set to Italian, how could i make number pipe work anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by setting manually `locale` in number pipe to `en-US`

So my input looks like this:

```
    <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control qta"
        [plu]="plu"
        appQuantity
        [min]="plu.um === 'PZ' ? 1 : .001"
        [step]="plu.um === 'PZ' ? 1 : .001"
        [value]="plu.um !== 'PZ' ? ( plu.qta | number: '1.3':'en-US' ) : plu.qta"
      />
```